# Fetch userData on EC2 machine boot up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda which triggers the EC2 machine to start using the amiId. When the lambda executes it also sends some userData to the EC2 machine instance which will be started.

Now, when i try to fetch the userData in the nodeJs code that will be executed on the EC2, it returs status 200 but the response body is empty.

Im using the api "http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data" with superagent npm module to make the request. Below is the code for request:

```
 request.get(config.awsUserDataUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            const schema = joi.object().keys({
                bucketname: joi.string().min(3).max(30).required(),
                // alphanumeric string of 24 characters in length
                jobid: joi.string().regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/),
                appid: joi.string().min(3).max(30).required(),
                snstopic: joi.string().min(3).max(60).required(),
                filepath: joi.string().min(3).max(60).required(),
            });
            logger.info('response', JSON.stringify(response.body));
            logger.info('response.body', response.body);
            logger.info('response.status', response.status);
            const result = joi.validate(response.body, schema);
            if (result.error === null) {
                logger.info('result', result);
                resolve(response.body);
            } else {
                logger.info('result.error', result.error);
                reject(result.error);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            logger.info('err.message', err.message);
            logger.info('err.response', err.response);

            // err.message, err.response
            reject(err);
        });
```

Note: I have not assigned any IAM role for EC2 in Lambda environment variable. Can the issue of not getting the response userData in EC2 be due to Role not assigned to EC2?

Comment: Can you view the user-data of the launched instance from AWS console?

Comment: Yes, i can see that in AWS console.

Comment: The url only works if called from inside the instance. Are you calling it from the Lambda?

Comment: @RodrigoM The url im calling is from the node code that is deployed on the EC2 machine whose ami is baked by Lambda.

Comment: No IAM role is needed for accessing user-data.  Test it with `curl`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it works with Curl on terminal when i login the machine in terminal.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is the above code correct to fetch the userData using superagent package?

Comment: I resolved this issue by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ec2-userdata

Answer (score 0):

It's terrible, but I think you need to put a busy-wait loop in front of your call, exiting when meta-data URL calls start giving HTTP 200 responses.

One of the odd quirks I've had with the meta-data URL is that it doesn't always exist "immediately" on boot.  One of the shell-based init scripts I use has a block of code like:

```
while [ ! "$(/usr/bin/curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)" = "200" ]
do
    echo "[Kira] Waiting for AWS metadata to exist"
    sleep 2
done
```

which just does a busy-wait until the data is available.  I do not believe that the choice of URL is relevant — I'm use that one in particular only because my script needs to know the AZ first.